# Strange behavior for PowerShell string match

Tags: string, powershell, match

When I write this in PowerShell,

```
$Person ="Guy Thomas 1949bhau"
$Person -Match "19?9"
```

It returns true.

But when I write this in PowerShell,

```
$Person ="Guy Thomas 1949bhau"
$Person -Match "19?9bhau"
```

it returns false.

What is the reason for this strange behavior? How is it returning true in the first place?

Comment: `-match` uses regex.  `?` means 0 or 1 previous characters.

Comment: What you're looking for is `-like`.  [`Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)

Comment: Because the sequence `19` exists in the string. It's looking for `199` OR `19` based on your match query.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 understood my mistake accepted below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing strange about the behavior. The `-match` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0#matching-operators) does [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) matches. In a regular expression the `?` is a special character with the meaning "zero or more times the preceding expression". Hence a (regular) expression `19?9` means "a one followed by zero or more nines and another nine" (matching `19`, `199`, `1999`, `19999`, etc.). To match exactly one arbitrary character you need to use `.`. However, in your case you probably want to match a digit (`\d` or `[0-9]`) rather than just any character.

If you want to use a wildcard match (where `?` means "any single character" and `*` means "zero or more characters") you need to use the `-like` operator. Beware, though, that while the `-match` operator matches the pattern anywhere inside a string (unless the pattern is anchored), the `-like` operator implicitly anchors the expression at beginning and end of the string unless you put `*` at the beginning and/or end of the pattern. `-like '19?9'` matches for instance "1979" and "19m9", but not "a1979" or "1979a". You need `-like '*19?9*'` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Or these options ...

```
$Person ="Guy Thomas 1949bhau"
$Pattern = '19?.*9'
(((Select-String -InputObject $Person -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches).Matches).Value)

Results

1949

$Person ="Guy Thomas 1949bhau"
$Pattern = '19?.*9*'
(((Select-String -InputObject $Person -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches).Matches).Value)

Resutls 

1949bhau
```

Or

```
[regex]::Matches($Person,$Pattern)

Results 

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 11
Length   : 8
Value    : 1949bhau
```

Or

```
[regex]::Matches($Person,$Pattern).Value

Results

1949bhau
```